# Reading a number when no input given in C++

Tags: c++, input, iostream, cin, istream

Is the following code prone to undefined behavior when end of file or an empty line is provided as input?

```
  unsigned long long i;
  cin >> i;
```

From what I've observed using Compiler Explorer, it seems `i` gets some random value, likely one that happened to be at that memory location. But it's often the case that when compilers behave this way, the standard in fact specifies UB.

Comment: Any code that does not check the return value of input to see if it succeeded or not is prone to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: `cin >> i;` can fail in a few different ways, and I believe it depends on exactly _when_ it fails what happens to `i`. If it successfully reads from the stream but fails to convert the value to an `unsigned long long`, it's [defined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) that `i` will be set to `0`. But if a failure takes place [earlier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction), "no input takes place", which would leave `i` uninitialized.

Comment: PSA: Use sensible type definitions like [`uint64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: @NathanPierson, the first case you described ("set to 0") is also explained at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt in the fragment starting with "If extraction fails". But nowhere at cppreference.com can I find anything about what `>>` does if  "no input takes place". Could you, please, point me to the relevant part (could be in the standard itself, or elsewhere, if it's something not covered by cppreference.com)?

Comment: @tadman — with the caution that, unlike `unsigned long long`, `uint64_t` is not required to exist.

Comment: @NathanPierson As I understand, this was pre-C++11, but it was corrected with LWG696.

Comment: @ByteEater  "This function behaves as a FormattedInputFunction. After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, extracts a value by calling std::num_get::get()." Then, this page on [FormattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) mentions "If the sentry returned false or sentry's constructor threw an exception, no input takes place".

Comment: @NathanPierson, I understand that no input takes place. But what happens then? How does `>>` react to such circumstance? By doing nothing to `i`? I can't see how it follows from anything linked so far.

Comment: @PeteBecker At least you'll get a compiler error instead of an unexpectedly tiny "long", which I think is a better deal.

Comment: @tadman What do you mean by "tiny"? `unsigned long long` is [guaranteed](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental) to be at least 64 bits long. Also, I don't see how in OP's case any specific size is required. Anyway, if only a minimum is important, he could use `uint_least64_t` instead (which is more portable than `uint64_t` because guaranteed to exist).

Comment: That's a good point. I assumed that "no input takes place" meant "nothing happens to `i`" (i.e. it's left uninitialized, or its previous value is left unchanged), but I don't know if there's any specific guarantees to that effect.

Comment: @heapunderrun, LWG696 deals only with `short` and `int` if I understand correctly (https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue696). Do I?

Comment: `if (!(cin >> i)) throw "sorry, things didn't work out";`

Comment: @tadman — fixed size integers might give a sense of security to people who don’t know how the sizes of integer types work, but choosing a fixed size type really should be based on sound analysis and not ignorance.

Comment: @Eljay, that's not what I asked for, but interesting in its own right. `<<` returns `basic_istream&`, so for your code to work an implicit conversion to `bool` is needed. Is there one for this type?

Comment: @ByteEater: Yes, there is. The class `std::istream` inherits the member function [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) from `std::basic_ios`.

Comment: This is a very basic thing to do in C++. Yet, somehow there are still no answers. What are acceptable ways on SO to draw more attention of people with relevant knowledge to this question? Please, any advice?

Comment: @ByteEater: One thing you could do is to issue a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). However, in your case, I would recommend to first improve the question with an [edit]. Editing your question will bump your question to the top of the question list for some people (depending on question filter settings), which may attract further attention to your question without the need of spending points on a bounty. One way to improve the question might be to include some of the concerns that you mentioned in the comments section inside the question itself.

Comment: @ByteEater: Your question is unclear in the following way: It is unclear whether you are asking (1) whether the two lines that you posted can themselves invoke undefined behavior, or (2) whether the two lines that you posted can easily lead to undefined behavior later in the program if one is not careful (for example if `i` contains an indeterminate value after executing the posted two lines and the program later attempts to read this value). For this reason, I would not recommend placing a bounty on your question until you have clarified your quesition in this respect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @AndreasWenzel. It's not unlikely that I'll use it another time. For this question, however, I've been convinced by Bing Chat and then reading the relevant articles at cppreference.com (most of them linked above) in that light that indeed `i` is unchanged. It retains its value if it had one or its uninitialized status otherwise.